# Python bindings for PCL (Point Cloud Library)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pcl

I am curently searching for some [Python](https://www.python.org/) 3.x bindings for [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) on Ubuntu (16.04).

The ones I found are:

- [pclpy](https://pypi.org/project/pclpy/): `pip` cannot find it.
- [python-pcl](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl): I have tried to install it but I always end up on errors with missing files or unmet dependencies or version issues... What is strange is that it is the only one listed on the PCL main page: http://pointclouds.org/news/tags/python !
- [PyPCL](https://pypi.org/project/PyPCL/): I can install it with `pip` but it's not documented at all.

Which one is the most used, the most efficient and up-to-date to process point clouds from Python?
Did I miss some other package(s)?

### Edit:

to answer properly the [1st comment below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296310/python-bindings-for-pcl?noredirect=1#comment476181_296310):

#### I tried to install [python-pcl](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl):

- 1st error along with many many warnings about deprecated functions:

  `pcl/_pcl_180.cpp: In function ‘int __pyx_pf_3pcl_4_pcl_18ConditionalRemoval___cinit__(__pyx_obj_3pcl_4_pcl_ConditionalRemoval*, __pyx_obj_3pcl_4_pcl_ConditionAnd*)’:
  pcl/_pcl_180.cpp:48508:153: error: no matching function for call to ‘pcl::ConditionalRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConditionalRemoval(__pyx_t_3pcl_15pcl_filters_180_ConditionBasePtr_t, NULL)’
  __pyx_v_self->me = new __pyx_t_3pcl_15pcl_filters_180_ConditionalRemoval_t(((__pyx_t_3pcl_15pcl_filters_180_ConditionBasePtr_t)__pyx_v_cond->me), NULL);`

My `PCL` version is `1.8.1`.

Comment: For python-pcl - did you follow the install instructions [here](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl)?  If you use conda, a prebuilt version is also available from the [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pcl) channel.

Comment: It doesn't work. I updated the main post about that. I use `pip`, not `conda`.

Comment: pclpy is supported for window only at this point, per to the documentation